# Count items in a list - ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, count

I have a search function on my website which takes text from a textbox control, compares it to the names of products in my database, adds the results to a list and then displays the product details in a repeater.

I would like to count the number of items in the list so that I can display some text like

> Search results for 'Jeans' (10 results found)

I already have the 'Search results for Jeans' bit but I can't work out how to count the list of my results variable.

**C#**

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchWord = txtWord.Text;

        ZaraEntities db = new ZaraEntities();

        var results = db.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchWord));

        rptrSearch.DataSource = results.ToList();
        rptrSearch.DataBind();

        litResults.Text = "<p>" + "Search results for " + "'" + txtWord.Text + "'" + "</p>";

    }
```

Comment: `results.Count()` maybe?

Comment: I must be missing something, It shouldn't be as simple as `.Count()`

Comment: @EZI you are not missing something the OP is missing something meaning where are they even getting the Count(); from the results. nor are they using it in the litResults.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchWord = txtWord.Text;

    ZaraEntities db = new ZaraEntities();

    var results = db.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchWord));

    rptrSearch.DataSource = results.ToList();
    rptrSearch.DataBind();

    litResults.Text = "<p>" + "Search results for " + "'" + txtWord.Text + "'" + " ("+ results.ToList().Count + ") Results found.</p>";

}
```

OR

```
litResults.Text = "<p>" + "Search results for " + "'" + txtWord.Text + "'" + " ("+ results.ToList().Count() + ") Results found.</p>";
```

**EDIT :**
Even better if you do it like that :

```
litResults.Text = string.Format("<p>Search results for {0} ({1}) Results found.</p>",txtWord.Text,results.ToList().Count);
```

Comment: would be much cleaner if you use the `string.Format()` function in my opinion and I fixed your formatting

Comment: yeah.. it would better for sure, it just wanted to provide him with the core solution he was asking for

Comment: Thank you. I was trying results.Count instead of results.ToList().Count which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: you're welcome .. keep improving ^_^